# Emacs GUI how to switch to text UI elements (widgets)

Tags: emacs

I switched from command prompt to Emacs GUI mode, I removed annoying menu/tool/scrollbars, I want to have smoother colors which works on GUI version.

Problem is that my eyes are bleeding when I see regular buttons inserted into text (ui widgets) and I'd like to have text version of them. I'd like to use Emacs GUI as "better cmd to run emacs -nw". I have tried unsuccessfully to switch to Linux on my main computer (as others run Linux) but at this point I don't feel like dual booting all the time.

TL;DR: Graphical UI widgets (buttons, checkboxes) -> Text version (like in emacs -nw)

Comment: Where else do you see buttons other than the toolbar at the top of the frame that you say has already been removed?  Are you talking about `M-x customize` or something other than just plain editing of text in a buffer?

Comment: For example if I switch my theme, I see buttons "Search" "Revert..." "Apply" etc as real buttons, not as text like "[Search]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'buttons' you are seeing are really just text with some font tricks to make them looked raised or 'boxed'. Completely getting rid of them may be a little tricky, but you should be able to remove most of them.

Emacs uses (in some places) an inheritance method to define 'faces', which means sometimes you may need to find the parent face to fix how it looks. These faces have attributes such as underline and box. For example, here is the definition for the 'button' face on my system.

```
Hide Button face: [sample]
    State : THEMED.
   Default face used for buttons.
   [ ] Font Family: --
   [ ] Font Foundry: --
   [ ] Width: --
   [ ] Height: --
   [ ] Weight: --
   [ ] Slant: --
   [X] Underline: Value Menu On:
       Color: Value Menu Foreground Color
       Style: Value Menu Line
   [ ] Overline: --
   [ ] Strike-through: --
   [ ] Box around text: --
   [ ] Inverse-video: --
   [ ] Foreground: --
   [ ] Distant Foreground: --
   [ ] Background: --
   [ ] Stipple: --
   [ ] Inherit: --
   Hide Unused Attributes
```

and here is the definition for

```
Hide Custom Button face: [sample]
    State : THEMED.
   Face for custom buffer buttons if ‘custom-raised-buttons’ is non-nil.
   [ ] Font Family: --
   [ ] Font Foundry: --
   [ ] Width: --
   [ ] Height: --
   [ ] Weight: --
   [ ] Slant: --
   [ ] Underline: --
   [ ] Overline: --
   [ ] Strike-through: --
   [X] Box around text: Value Menu Box:
       Width: 2
       Color: Value Menu *
       Style: Value Menu Raised
   [ ] Inverse-video: --
   [X] Foreground: #93a1a1     Choose   (sample)
   [ ] Distant Foreground: --
   [X] Background: #073642     Choose   (sample)
   [ ] Stipple: --
   [ ] Inherit: --
   Hide Unused Attributes
```

Note the underline and box attributes used by these two faces.

What you need to do is change the attributes so that the face doesn't cause your eyes to bleed. There are two ways (actaully ther are more, but two are easy to describe!) you can do this.

M-x list-faces-display

> list-faces-display is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘faces.el’.
>
> It is bound to  ,    .
>
> (list-faces-display &optional REGEXP)
>
> List all faces, using the same sample text in each. The sample text is
>   a string that comes from the variable ‘list-faces-sample-text’.
>
> If REGEXP is non-nil, list only those faces with names matching this
>   regular expression.  When called interactively with a prefix argument,
>   prompt for a regular expression using ‘read-regexp’.

and M-x customize-face (point needs to be on the face you want to customise or you need to know the name of it)

> customize-face is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘cus-edit.el’.
>
> It is bound to    .
>
> (customize-face &optional FACE OTHER-WINDOW)
>
> Customize FACE, which should be a face name or nil. If FACE is nil,
>   customize all faces.  If FACE is actually a face-alias, customize the
>   face it is aliased to.
>
> If OTHER-WINDOW is non-nil, display in another window.
>
> Interactively, when point is on text which has a face specified,
>   suggest to customize that face, if it’s customizable.

My suggestion would be to use list-faces-display and go through the list to identify those faces which you don't like and then change them to something acceptable. This should get most of them. Then, when using emacs, when you find another 'button' hyou don't like, put the cursor on it and use customize-face to change it.

Note that loading themes can also change face settings, so you may need to get the sequence of things right to get consistent behaviour.

Comment: Oh, great job! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `(setq custom-raised-buttons nil)`.  This will make buttons in customize buffers look more like flat text.  You can change other attributes by putting the cursor on the thing you think is ugly and doing `M-x customize-face RET`.  Finally, you may want to try out some themes; there are dozens in [Melpa](https://melpa.org) (search for "-theme").

Comment: "(setq custom-raised-buttons nil)" made it so that those are still buttons but the text in the buttons are inside square brackets.

Comment: Looking closer, `custom-raised-buttons` is sort of special when it comes to variables.  Set it before `cus-edit.el` loads (or reload with `M-x load-library RET cus-edit RET`); even then it only applies to new customize buffers.  There is some code that uses the value, and it only gets run when the file is loaded.  It should be sufficient to set the variable in your init file and restart Emacs.